# JS / HTML : Adding class to parent of search input not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I'm trying to select the parent DIV of a search input so that I can change the background color when the search input is focused. I'm confused why this code isn't working. Thanks for any help.

http://jsfiddle.net/BZ5uf/1/

HTML

```
<div class="search">  
   <input class="box" value="Search" onfocus="if(this.value=='Search') this.value='';" onblur="(this.value=='') this.value='Search';">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.search {
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px; 
    width: 300px;
    height: 65px;
    border: 1px solid black;

}
input.box { 
    margin: 10px;
}

.fill {
    background: #222;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(function(){
    $('.box').focus(function(){
        $(this).parent().addClass('fill');
 )};
```

Comment: It's `background-color` not `background`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax error galore.

```
)}; //mismatched order
```

Should be

```
    });
}); //you also forgot to close DOM ready handler
```

Also experiment using the "JSHint" button in the top of your fiddle.

Good IDEs will highlight those errors for you too. Also using proper indentation helps finding unclosed handlers:

```
$(function () {
    $('.box').focus(function () {
        $(this).parent().addClass('fill');
    });
});
```

The above format is obtained using jsfiddle's "TidyUp" button. Here's your [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BZ5uf/11/).

Answer (score 2):

[Working example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/htmled/P6EjN/).

```
$('.box').on('blur', function () {
    $(this).parent()
           .addClass('fill');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your JavaScript:

change this :

```
$('.box').focus(function(){
    $(this).parent().addClass('fill');
)};
```

to :

```
$('.box').focus(function(){
    $(this).parent().addClass('fill');
});
```

(note the flipped brace order)

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your JS, it should be like this

```
$(function(){
    $('.box').focus(function(){
         $(this).parent().addClass('fill');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you had a syntax error.  Here's the correct code:

```
$(function(){
    $('.box').focus(function(){
        $(this).parent().addClass('fill');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
   $(function(){
    $('.box').focus(function(){
        $(this).parent().addClass('fill');
    });
});
```